# Having trouble increasing iterator with multiple for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I am a beginner in Python and I decided to attempt a script to help me in my part time job as a weather observer.  Essentially, I have a list of observations and I have written regex's to gather the information that I need and put it in a spreadsheet using xlwings.  I have a list of partial observations and I am trying to extract the sky condition from these partial obs.  The sky condition contains any of the words that I have in the list called "words".  I am sure there is a much better way to do this but I am trying to have the script look at the items in each element of the list and then determine whether or not one of the key words is in the element.  If it finds one, I am adding it to a new list called 'found' and then I eventually want to add this information to the excel spreadsheet.  My problem is I am having trouble finding where to increment over the different sky conditions.  I need it to iterate over each element in a line on the skycons list, then I need it to increment to the next line.  I feel like I have moved the increment to several different parts of the script but it still won't work properly.  It will either increment too soon and will not iterate over all the elements of the line or it will not increment at all.  Here is the code...

```
 skycons = [' -RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' R02/2600VP6000FT -RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' -RA BR SCT007 BKN013 OVC019 09/08 ',
 ' CLR 09/08 ']
 

i = 0
words = ['FEW', 'SCT', 'BKN', 'OVC', 'CLR']
found = []
for item in skycons[i].split():
    print(skycons[i].split())
    for word in words:
        print(word)        
        if item.startswith(word):            
            found += item
            print(found)
    sky = " ".join(found)
    print(sky)
    i+=1
```

This may be a mess and I am open to suggestions.  I am basically needing to grab the sky condition from each observation and insert it in a spreadsheet.  I have tried doing this strictly with a regex but it would end up grabbing other elements of the observation that is not present in the above list.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith): "*prefix* can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for". But you don't need it at all, you can just iterate over `skycons` and check `if any(word in item for word in words)`.

Comment: Please show your expected output. That will help us more than reading those paragraphs.

Comment: expected output would be, for the first line in skycons - BKN008 OVC012, second and third line would be the same.  3rd - SCT007 BKN013 OVC019, final - CLR.  These are what I would expect to be in "sky" and is what i would append to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`found += item` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Look at this:

```
>>> found = []
>>> found += 'OVC'
>>> found
['O', 'V', 'C']
```

I don't think that's what you're expecting. It appends each character to the list, not the entire string. Try `append()` instead:

```
found.append(item)
```

Also, `i` isn't getting incremented at the right times. I think you need another outer loop to go through the METARs. Here's what I ended up with:

```
skycons = [' -RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' R02/2600VP6000FT -RA BR BKN008 OVC012 09/08 ',
 ' -RA BR SCT007 BKN013 OVC019 09/08 ',
 ' CLR 09/08 ']
 

words = ['FEW', 'SCT', 'BKN', 'OVC', 'CLR']
for metar in skycons:
    found = []
    for item in metar.split():
        for word in words:
            if item.startswith(word):            
                found.append(item)
    sky = " ".join(found)
    print(sky)
```

... which outputs...

```
 BKN008 OVC012
 BKN008 OVC012
 BKN008 OVC012
 SCT007 BKN013 OVC019
 CLR
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!   This worked great!  I knew it wasn't right but wasn't sure how to work around.  +1 on the METAR!!